# Nodejs run js error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I can't run node src/index.js it throws errors.
But nodemon is ok. How do i run a production version of it ?

```
PS D:\Development\server\Image hosting\node-express-server-rest-api-master> node   src/index.js
D:\Development\server\Image hosting\node-express-server-rest-api-master\src\index.js:2
import cors from 'cors';

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

It's a Very simple project and the files:  I tried the    "type": "module", But it throws new error.
Nothing works dispite this is just a example project

**package.json**:

```
{
"name": "node-express-server-rest-api",
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "Node imgs hosting",
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production node src/index.js",
    "win-prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && node   src/index.js"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.13.0",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  }
 }
```

index.js

```
require('dotenv/config');
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';


import routes from './routes';
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();


app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use((req, res, next) => {
// req.context = {
//     models,
//     me: models.users[1],
// };
next();
});


app.use('/upload', routes.upload);


app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
 console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
);
```

Comment: If you look at your start script you'll see it runs using `babel-node`. To deploy this you'll want to use webpack or a similar solution that bundles modules together into a single file. However you can simply use `require()` instead.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it? No need code split

Comment: Just replace `import cors from 'cors';` with `const cors = require('cors');`, same for the other import lines.

Comment: I also have another project which got a lot of import. And i don't think this is a solution.

Comment: ...yeah, I also have lots of projects that use `import`, but they are set up accordingly so that using `import` actually works. Classic node/express uses `require()`, which you can also see here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: I just rrn it with nodemon on Pm2 and i hope it won't have problem. And this is just a script for image uploading

Comment: Don't use `nodemon` for production; it's meant for hot-reloading during development. Just replace the three imports with requires, I don't understand what the issue is with that? `nodemon` doesn't fix the `import` issue, `babel-node` does that.

Comment: I won't touch these files where in somewhere on my Server. I think it will be allright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll Post the answer here.

Add this module: `npm i esm`

Add one more file under the root folder
I'll name it as main.js:

```
require = require("esm")(module /*, options*/ )
module.exports = require("./src/index.js")
```

Change the package.json start script
From this:

```
 "win-prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && node -r src/index.js"
```

into this:

```
 "win-prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && node -r esm main.js"
```